# ¿Cómo comprimir el siguiente ciclo for?

Tags: python, lista

Sigo trabajando en la comprensión de ciclos **for** en listas y ahora estoy desarrollando un programa simple para calcular los factores de un número. Pero, a la hora de intentar comprimir el ciclo, me confundo un poco y me atoro.
Esto es lo que llevo:

```
factores = [numero if (numero % x == 0)  else x = x + 1 for i in range(1, numero)] #La variable **numero** es un número aleatorio
```

Como ven, no sé cómo implementar las condicionales **if and else** dentro de la comprensión de listas y eso me falla mucho.

Este es el código del ciclo **for**:

```
for j in range(1, numero): #La variable **numero** es un número aleatorio
        if (numero % x == 0): #La variable **x** es un entero (2)
            print(str(x) + " ")
            g=(str(x) + " ")
            numero = numero / x 
            result.append(f'{g}\n')
        else:
            x = x + 1
```

¿Cómo corrijo este problema? De antemano muchas gracias, saludos!

Comment: las compresiones solo admiten un `if`

Comment: aunque en tu *compresión de lista* estas empleando un tipo de operador ternario, donde tu lista tendrá un solo valor. Se agrega `numero` si la compresión retorna `True` y luego faltaría el `else`. SIntaxis -> `<valor> if <condicion> else <Valor_secundario>`

Comment: Tal vez una de las formas más sencillas de calcular los factores: `[i for i in range(1,x+1) if x%i==0]`, te recomiendo ver:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es de concepto sobre la [comprensión de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

**El objetivo** de la comprensión de listas es tan solo **devolver una lista realizando una operación con un ciclo `for`**, esta estructura **no está creada con el proposito de ir cambiando variables** durante el ciclo `for` con un filtrado. Por supuesto se puede conseguir usando expresiones generadoras, o una comprensión de listas doble (todo es posible en programación). Pero es bastante tedioso de hacer y como resultado te va a quedar una expresión con una legibilidad muy difícil para otros programadores.

Teniendo esto en mente puedes hacer dos cosas para tu problema, quedar el código como está con el ciclo `for` inicial. Tomar la alternativa de Patricio Moracho, de implementar la misma idea de otra forma.

### Bonus

Aunque sé que lo haces por aprender, esto también es parte del aprendizaje, saber el por qué se han creado las distintas sintaxis, y cuando deben utilizarse.